# How does one login to a website using Axios HTTP Client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, web-scraping, axios

I am trying to login to a website using Axios HTTP Client in Node JS with no success.

If the login is successful, I should be redirected to the homepage with my username showing in the navigation panel but what happens is that I am redirected to the homepage showing guest in the navigation panel meaning I am not yet logged in.

What could be the problem?

Here's my code:
    var axios = require('axios');

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://www.nairaland.com/';
axios.defaults.headers.common['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.70 Safari/537.36';

var axiosRes, axiosErr;

axios.post('do_login', {
    name: '********@gmail.com',
    password: '********'
})
.then(function (response) {
    axiosRes = response;

    console.log(axiosRes);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    axiosErr = error;
});
```

Comment: Where do you redirect? Add the related code please.

Comment: After logging in @ www.nairaland.com/do_login, I should be taken to the homepage showing "Welcome, savvysage" but rather I am taking to the homepage showing "Welcome, guest" meaning I am not yet logged in. Code is available above.

Comment: This code is not enough to answer your question,  show the code how do you redirect.

Comment: I didn't redirect. It's not my website.

Comment: The code doesn't "take" you anywhere. It logs a variable. Are you saying `axiosRes` shows some HTML with "Welcome, guest" in it?

Comment: It's logs the response to the console. The response headers and data will be displayed in the console.

Comment: The `do_login` endpoint is likely returning a token or other authentication artifact which you will need to supply when you redirect to the homepage. What does the console.log print?

I would take a look at cypress if I were you. Much higher level interaction.

Comment: Here: https://codeshare.io/UbKVU

Comment: You have to do extra cookie stuff for this which is why I use superagent.agent()